# Mondrian - why do I need explicit level to reference a member in a hierarchy?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

If I want to reference a member in a hierarchy in a Mondrian MDX query (using Mondrian 4.4), I have to reference the level explicitly in the expression.  For example, in SSAS I can do something like

`[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Canada]`

but in Mondrian I have to add the name of the first hierarchy level explicitly

`[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country-Region].[Canada]`

Where should I be looking to troubleshoot?   My hierarchy is simple, with only two levels and `hasAll="false"`.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SSAS` when you write this `[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Canada]` I believe that it is short-hand for this:

```
[Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[Canada]
```

These two scripts give the same result:

```
SELECT 
  [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All].[Canada] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];

SELECT 
  [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Canada] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

So if your hierarchy has no `[All]` member the members will be children of the highest level. I think `SSAS` will assume the highest level even if you do not explicitly state it but it looks like `mondrian` needs it explicitly adding in to your `mdx`.

Comment: @GregGalloway am I correct with the above in respect of SSAS ?

Comment: I think you are... https://devmau5.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/isaggregatable-false/

Comment: I guess `IsAggregatable` of `SSAS` is similar to `hasAll` of `IsAggregatable`

Comment: So - is the issue that SSAS supports some short-hand syntax that Mondrian does not?

Comment: @wrschneider - that is what I'm assuming although I'm not 100%. Can you add the question to a `mondrian` user group - even though I don't use `mondrian` I'd be interested to know if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, I have also asked on the Mondrian forum.  No responses.
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?197981-Level-required-in-MDX-set-expression-to-reference-member-in-hierarchy